# Opening facebook in a panel of winforms

Tags: c#, multithreading, facebook, panel, process.start

I am in need to open facebook(whatsapp,skype etc) with in a panel. please suggest something to achieve the same. I working on windows 7. If facebook is not possible then please suggest with whatever the task is possible whether with facebook messenger,whatsapp (site or app),skype or any other social networking site or app.

Answer (score 1):

try this

Process.Start("http://www.google.com");

or

If the point is to open a website in your application, you will have to use WebBrowser control. Put WebBrowser control on your form, and add this code to the button which is responsible for opening the site:

webBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com");

Comment: thanks ! and is it possible to resize the content of web page according to size of the panel ?

Comment: Yes, jUst make your website responsive and fix the size of the panel

Comment: Yes ..just i had to rezise the webbrowser control to fit the content or have to use zoom in or zoom-out to fit the content, but that is what we have to do manually. I was looking for something that can adjust the site according to webbrowser control size at run time.

Comment: oh sorry, i didn't know that